# Replacing responsive tables for better markup and accessibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a site with a set of images that can be viewed by scrolling the page vertically or by clicking a button that links to the next image in the set using an anchor tag.

The images are centered vertically and horizontally inside a container that responds to the size of the browser window.

```
<a id="1">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr valign="middle"><td align="center">

        <img src="image.png">
    
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
 
        <a href="#2">Down</a>
    
    </td></tr>
    </table>

</a>
```

I know of no other way to achieve this but to use tables though I am aware that it is very poor markup.

I have also found that the site renders correctly in Firefox 16.0.2 but not in Safari 5.0.6 where after the second image in the set the tables appear to grow in height exponentially.

How can I code this site for better accessibility and with proper markup?

Comment: Always include an example image of what you want which including a link.  If the link goes down this question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: Thanks, I've added code to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would probably do it without resorting to too many hacks would be to just put each image in a div, set some dimensions based on css, then use javascript to adjust accordingly.
Here is the sample HTML:

```
div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.focus-itoutsourcing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Software-testing-trends-2013.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.focus-itoutsourcing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Software-testing-trends-2013.jpg" />
</div>
```

The sample CSS:

```
html {height:100%;}
body {height:100%;}

div.item {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

div.item > img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

And finally the jquery which simply readjusts sizes on resize and at the start.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Setup function for sizing.
    var win = $(window), body = $('body');
    var els = $('div.item');
    function DoResize() {
        var height = win.height(), 
        width = body.width();
        els.each(function(i,el){
            var ele = $(el);
            ele.height(height).width(width);
            var img = ele.find('img');
            var difference = (height - img.height())/2.0;
            img.css('margin-top',difference+'px');
        });
    }
    
    DoResize();
    $(window).on('resize', DoResize);
});
```

I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hgwx8Lg/) for you to see it in action.  It also readjusts for resizing of the window. It should work in most browsers even IE7 according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com).

#### Update:

To include the captions and such you can do a variety of things.  The easiest would be to add relative positioning to each item, then absolute positioning to each element you want to position with respect to each image.

You would do the html more or less like so:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.focus-itoutsourcing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Software-testing-trends-2013.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
        Caption for Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="link">
        <a href="javascript:alert('Woo #1');">Item link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the style would just have updates for the other classes within the parent div.

I updated the jsfiddle here to show you some things you can do: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2hgwx8Lg/3/)

#### Updated again:

Add the following script tag to your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before the Resizing script.

Comment: Thanks. Your jsfiddle looks right but I haven't been able to recreate it [here](http://www.leecorbin.co/design/index-12-jquery.html). I'm sure I'm not implementing the jquery correctly. Also, how would you deal with the corresponding captions and hyperlink that appeared at the bottom of each table in my [first example](http://www.leecorbin.co/design/index-12.html)?

Comment: I also see your problem.  You didn't include jquery before the script.  Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: No problem. I hosted the jquery file locally which worked until I swapped the link with the one you posted, I'm not sure why. Do I need to specify a doctype on the page? I also notice that the image is rendered somewhat below vertical center – easier to see on this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hgwx8Lg/10/). How can I correct that?

Comment: Have to add padding:0;margin:0; to the body style to get rid of the extra spacing. As for the script, It might be the // syntax.  Putting http: infront may help

Comment: Yes, specifying the padding and margin and adding "http://" before the script resolved both issues. It's buggy though. When the page loads and upon refresh the first image appears half-way down the page, see ![this image](http://www.leecorbin.co/design/1.tiff). It is only when I alter the size of the browser window that the images move into the center of page. [Here it is so far.](http://www.leecorbin.co/design/index-12-jquery.html)

Comment: You can change the part towards the end where I call the first time `DoResize();` instead with `$(window).load(function(){DoResize();});` That will execute the first time once images have loaded.  You can combine it with some styles to make it prettier/hide the loading

Comment: I added a new jsfiddle to show you.  Note I set the option in the left bar for the javascript to be put in the header not wrapped for onLoad, since we want to deal with it. Here´s the link: http://jsfiddle.net/2hgwx8Lg/13/

Comment: You've given me a lot to work with here. What doctype should I use to run this code?

Comment: I usually prefer to just go with `<!DOCTYPE html>` for HTML5 compatibility

Comment: I'm running your script to responsively center an image on a page in conjunction with a script that displays a corresponding caption. There are multiple images on the page and the captions change as the page is scrolled up and down. When the top of an image moves past the top of the window, the caption for the next image appears.

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/admiringtheorchid/2hgwx8Lg/17/) the caption for the next image appears when the top of the container (outlined by a solid pixel) moves past the top of the window. I need to find a way to distinguish between the top of the actual image and the top of its container for the transition to work properly. Can you make a suggestion?

Comment: You can use measure the window position on scroll, then compare it to your containers' offset.  If a container offset gets passed by scroll position then make the correct label visible.  That can be handled purely javascript or a combination javascript/css (to handle appearing and disappearing).

Comment: How would that differ from the execution of the code as it is now?

Answer (score 1):

Damn Miltox beat me too it. His is better though. Just to say the reason safari was weird was you had multiple tables set at 100% height each stacked on top of each other so they were adding up, you should have had one big table. Miltox's answer will have fixed that all anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Would I then place each image in a table cell that would be 100% of the height and width of the browser window?